# Bootstrap datepicker hide after selection

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

How do I hide the calendar after a date is selected? Is there a specific function that I can use? My code below:

```
$('#dp1').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    startDate: '-15d',
    autoclose: true,
    endDate: '+0d' // there's no convenient "right now" notation yet
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why isn't this the default behavior of the library?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can use event `changedate()` to keep track of when the date is changed together with `datepicker('hide')` method to hide the `datepicker` after making selection:

```
$('yourpickerid').on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ymp5D/165/)

**UPDATE**

This was the bug with `autoclose: true`. This bug was fixed in latest master. SEE THE <kbd>**[COMMIT](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/commit/bf1b2c820076e3e11b0199abe43d00ddcc645995)**</kbd>. Get the latest code from <kbd>**[GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js)**</kbd>

Comment: I would recommend additionally checking if current view mode is 'days' : `if (ev.viewMode === 'days') {$(this).datepicker('hide');}` as you probably don't want to hide datepicker after selecting a month or a year}

Comment: It's looks like autoclose is set to false by default... `$(".date").datepicker({... autoclose: true, ...  });` works nice !!!

Answer (score 49):

If it's any help to anyone, the Version 2.0 of the bootstrap datepicker no longer works with the accepted answer.

Here's how I got it working on mine:

```
$('yourpickerid').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
}).on('changeDate', function(e){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

See http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#changedate

Comment: There's a version 2? I see v1.6.4 as the latest release on Github

Comment: Use autoclose (see @Salim's answer or the updated accepted answer) instead of handling the event manually. If you hide the datepicker when the date is changed, then attempting to type in the date can cause unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 44):

```
$('#input').datepicker({autoclose:true});
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Simply open the `bootstrap-datepicker.js`
2. find : `var defaults = $.fn.datepicker.defaults`
3. set `autoclose: true`

Save and refresh your project and this should do.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to override the behavior of the calendar in general, globally, try editing the Datepicker function (in my example it was line 82),

from

```
    this.autoclose = false;
```

to

```
    this.autoclose = true;
```

Worked fine for me, as I wanted to have all my calendar instances behave the same.

Comment: No need to change the default properties in the js library. You can pass it as a property of the object to the function when you call it. Example: $('#dob').datepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', autoclose:true});

Answer (score 4):

The problem can be stopped, blocking hide event for input element by this linese:

```js
var your_options = { ... };
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(your_options).on('hide', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate ! i was getting mad because the input got hidden after date selection, and this solved my problem. Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

Close datetimepicker when date select(datetimepicker show  date with time)

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    closeOnDateSelect: true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In bootstrap 4 use "autoHide : true"

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
    autoHide: true,
    format: 'mm-yyyy',
    endDate: new Date()
});
```

Comment: Nice answer Ankit

Answer (score 1):

```
$('yourpickerid').datetimepicker({
           pickTime: false
}).on('changeDate', function (e) {
           $(this).datetimepicker('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Having problem with clock still showing even if I i wrote format: **'YYYY-MM-DD'**,

I hade to set `pickTime: false` and after **change->hide** I hade to **focus->show**

```
$('#VBS_RequiredDeliveryDate').datetimepicker({
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  pickTime: false
});

$('#VBS_RequiredDeliveryDate').on('change', function(){
    $('.datepicker').hide();
});

$('#VBS_RequiredDeliveryDate').on('focus', function(){
    $('.datepicker').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change source code, **bootstrap-datepicker.js**.
Add `this.hide();` like ne

```
  if (this.viewMode !== 0) {
    this.date = new Date(this.viewDate);
    this.element.trigger({
        type: 'changeDate',
        date: this.date,
        viewMode: DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].clsName
    });
    this.hide();//here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a perfect solution:

```
$('#Date_of_Birth').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (e) {
    if(e.viewMode === 'days')
        $(this).blur();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
});
```

Comment: Another answer on this question is exactly the same as yours. OP also has this `autoclose: true` in their example code.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to **datetimepicker** and format to **'DD/MM/YYYY'**

```
$("id").datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
}).on('changeDate', function() {
    $('.datepicker').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For datetime picker

```
$('yourpickerid').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
}).on('changeDate', function(e){
        $(this).datetimepicker('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in version 2.2.3 that I'm using, you must use `autoClose` instead of `autoclose`. Letter case matters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for datetimepicker, it works fine

```
$('#Date').data("DateTimePicker").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen this mentioned, but this is what fixed it for me:

```
switchOnClick: true
```